# Share image intent doesn't work in Samsung S8

Tags: android, image, share, samsung-mobile

I have this method for share screenshot from a view.

```
try {
            File mPath = new File(getContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), new Date() + ".png");
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(mPath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

            final Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri pictureUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), getContext().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".example.provider", mPath);
            i.setType("image/*");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "example" + SPACE + getShareStringForDate() + "image" + PLAY_STORE + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID);
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pictureUri);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, getResources().getString(R.string.shareImageWith)));
        } catch (Throwable tr) {
            Utiles.showToastLong(getResources().getString(R.string.error), getActivity());
        }
```

This solutions works perfectly but I have an user with problems, when he press, doesn't open the dialog, but not fail nothing. 
Their phone is a Samsung S8.

Why doesn't work? Can you help me?

Comment: Because Samsung. What is the issue because `I have an user with problems` is very vague? Do you have any logs?

Comment: Post your exception trace

Comment: The dialog doesn't open for him, and catch doesn't throw.

Comment: I can't post my exception trace because don't generate nothing.

Comment: Put a breakpoint and walk through the code line by line, checking everything, for example, is the right Uri generated.